# How to map Alt+Tab behavior to another keyboard combination?

Tags: unix, keyboard-shortcuts

At work, I have a desktop PC running on Windows. Then we use remote access for the development on Unix thru VNC.

In my current setting, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> triggers a switch in Windows.
VNC as also an options to send <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to Unix.

But I would prefer a third solution. I'd like to keep <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> for Windows, and create another mapping for Unix. For example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Is there a solution?

I don't know if this is useful but our unix machines are running Redhat4-5 and the desktop is xfce.

Answer (score 0):

on the Unix machine edit the file ~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml and change this line:

```
<property name="&lt;Alt&gt;Tab" type="string" value="cycle_windows_key"/>
```

to:

```
<property name="&lt;Ctrl&gt;Tab" type="string" value="cycle_windows_key"/>
```

Comment: Hi, I'll check that next week when I'll get back to work. Thanks for your time!